# How to format my dual boot HDD with windows and ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows, format

I started installing Ubuntu 12.10 on my windows 7 (64bit), but then I installed a new windows and therefore deleted the old windows.

I now want to uninstall Ubuntu and GRUB, but my WUBI-uninstaller.exe is not working, and I can't seem to find the Linux partition on my hard drive.

I just want to do a complete format of my HDD without rendering it useless...

Comment: Hey Thomas, it sounds like you're talking about several different things.  When you "format" a HDD, it essentially erases everything on the HDD (unless you format by partition). Secondly, you mention WUBI but it sounds more like you installed Ubuntu using the non-WUBI installer.  You'd only use `WUBI-uninstaller.exe` if you installed using WUBI.  I believe WUBI still uses Windows' built-in OS selector so it doesn't make GRUB your default boot loader.

Comment: I have (deleted it now) the C:\ubuntu and C:\wubildr files, so I'm pretty sure I did a Wubi installation. Although it's so long ago, that I can't remember anymore. Fact is, I don't know how to get rid of Ubuntu, so I can install a clean new windows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comments, you mention:

> I don't know how to get rid of Ubuntu, so I can **install a clean new windows OS**

If this is all you want to do, then you don't need to uninstall anything.

> **STOP:** Be careful, the following steps will *delete all data from your hard drive. If this is not what you want, then you're using the word "format" incorrectly.

Simply run your Windows install CD from boot.  During installation, the Windows installer will ask if you want to Reinstall Windows, Upgrade Windows, and/or Install from Scratch (though it might use different wording). Indicate that you want to install from scratch.

There may be another option allowing you to format the hard drive.  Make sure this is selected (or that you answer "Yes").

PS: You may have to select something similar to "Advanced Install/Setup" in order to see it.

Comment: Okay, so now I've pressed install, and it started installing windows right away, so I pressed cancel. Next time I boot, it says BOOTMGR IS MISSING, and I cannot format the HDD...

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Pressed that format button, and resumed the installation. Apparently my motherboard wants it to install as a GPT Hard drive, but since I'm not gonna use RAID, I won't need that.

Comment: Glad to help :) Thanks for accepting my answer -- Feel free to also hit the "upvote" button!

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu with `wubi`, you don't have a separate partition for it. The Ubuntu installation resides in folders on your main drive (usually `C:`).

To remove Ubuntu, delete the folders called `C:\ubuntu` and `C:\wubildr*`

After that  you can use the built-in `bcdedit` command  to edit the boot menu. To use `bcdedit`, run `cmd.exe` as an administrator, then enter `bcdedit` to show all boot entries, note the `{GUID}` specified for the Ubuntu entry, and then remove it:

```
 bcdedit /delete {GUID}
```

To remove Wubi from the add/remove list, delete the registry key:

```
 HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
```

After deleting the registry key, Ubuntu may still appear in the program list. If this is the case, you may be asked if you would like to remove the item from the list.

Comment: There is no Wubi in the add/remove list??

Comment: And another thing is, that I've removed the C:\ubuntu and C:\wubildr, but I can still log on Ubuntu in dual-boot. It is fully operatable..

Comment: Please specify the steps of your installation(s), when you used wubi and when the normal install.